# AlertDialog and Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to create a contact application so far so good,(I'm new to Android Developing) but I struggle with this part of the code where I have an AlertDialog, that I want from the elements that displays (infos of the contact, selected), to take me to my Activity, (ActivitySMS.class to be exact), but although it seems to be fine, running the app, and selecting the number from the AlertDialog that appears, it ends. Log doesn't show something worthy of exploring and understanding where lies the problem.

```
public class AgendaActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_agenta);

    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor mCursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    String[] contacts = {
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
    };

    int[] views = new int[]{
            android.R.id.text1
    };

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            mCursor,
            contacts,
            views,
            0);

    // Bind to our new adapter.
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    final Cursor phoneCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
            new String[]{"" + id},
            null);

    assert phoneCursor != null;
    final int nTelephones = phoneCursor.getCount();
    final String[] telephones = new String[nTelephones];
    int x = 0;

    while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
        int col = phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        telephones[x++] = phoneCursor.getString(col);
    }

    //Cursor Close
    phoneCursor.close();

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Telephone Selection");
    builder.setItems(telephones, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int item) {

            String currentNumber = "smsto: " + (telephones[item]);

            Intent sentIntent = new Intent(AgendaActivity.this, ActivitySMS.class);
            sentIntent.setData(Uri.parse(currentNumber));



            startActivity(sentIntent);
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Is there a way to overcome this obstacle?

Comment: still you should post your logs.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line `sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse(currentNumber));` by

```
public static final String EXTRA_CURRENT_NUMBER = "EXTRA_CURRENT_NUMBER"; //just a string constant, it can be whatever you want
...
sendIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CURRENT_NUMBER, currentNumber);
```

You can read that value later in your activity like this

```
//ActivitySMS.class
getIntent().getExtras().getString(MyDialogClass.EXTRA_CURRENT_NUMBER, "some default value...");
```